# Magento 2 : Not able to save admin form after adding multiple tabs

Tags: magento2, adminform

I have created an admin form with 2 tabs. 2nd tab contains product grid. Before adding tabs save button works perfectly but now getting an error

> TypeError: $.data(...) is undefined

and I'm not able to save the form. Used this link for adding product grid:
http://www.webspeaks.in/2016/05/magento-2-add-products-grid-to-custom-admin-module.html

Comment: have you check error log ? what error are you facing while saving the data ?

Comment: Which is your Magento version?

Comment: Magento ver. 2.1.0

Comment: For 2.1.0, you can try this module: https://github.com/mrkhoa99/Boolfly_ProductRelation

Comment: Have you run depoy command, php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: Yes. I did that.

Comment: Have you found out the solution. I have an issue like that